# How to ensure referential integrity many not strictly hierarchical entities?

Tags: sql, database, referential-integrity

Say I have three entities(or tables): `School`, `Student` and `Classroom`. How do I ensure a `Student` belongs to a `Classroom` which belongs to the same `School` the `Student` belongs to? Considering a `Student` may not be part of any Classroom.

I'm facing that problem in many other ways. For example, when I add the entity `Teacher`. How can I guarantee at database level that a `Teacher` teaches on a `Classroom` of the same `School` the `Teacher` belongs to? And so on...

Comment: Can a teacher teach for a different school?  Can a student take classes in more than one school?

Comment: No, they can't, although they can change of school. But then the teacher can no longer teach in the previous school, and then student can no longer be in a classroom of the previous school.

Comment: Your problem is harder than it sounds.  Don't try to enforce those relationships in the database, because the don't exist.  A teacher might belong to one school one year and another the next year, but you've only allowed the teacher to have one school.